# Flex AS3: Dynamically Create Graphic with BitmapImage Child

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, bitmapimage, graphic

I've trawled the net trying to find a solution, but everything seems to be mxml-centric.  What I want is to dynamically create a series of Graphics objects each with a child BitmapImage.  However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
   var bmi:BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
   bmi.source="@Embed('custom-case.png')";
   var gr:Graphic = new Graphic( );
   gr.addElement( bmi );
   gr.x = 50;
   gr.y = 50;
   this.addElement( gr );
```

Whereas, this does:

```
   <s:Graphic x="250" y="250">
    <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('custom-case.png')">
    </s:BitmapImage>
   </s:Graphic>
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is quite different in AS3, you have to define a variable class type like shown below.

```
[Embed("custom-case.png")]
 private var someImage:Class;
 ...
 bmi.source=someImage;
```

Comment: Hi @rxx I am trying to load Image source dynamically of already created mxml image component. When I used ur code it gives error as "Private attribute can only be used on class property definition", then I amde it public then also it gives error for public as well. Can u suggest the problem

Comment: Hi Shruti, I am no more working on AS stuff and I have no clue, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up Shruti's comment/question (I am unable to post comment since my current reputation insufficent):

The requirement for dynamic updating of images with mxml is the same as indicated with the original answer, which is that any images you might want to dynamically change to must be pre-embeded in your mxml:

```
[Embed(source="image.png")] private var theImage:Class;
```

which can be later used to update an image source as such:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[           
    [Embed(source="image.png")] private var theImage:Class;

    private function updateImage():void {
        image.source = theImage;
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:BitmapImage id="image" source="@Embed('defaultImage.png')"/>
```